# Ending A Session, Reset Variables Not Working?

Tags: php, session, redirect, session-variables, logout

I am writing a script which is supposed to end a session for a user, and log them out of the system, thus returning them to the login page.

My logout script looks like this:

```
<?php

$_SESSION['signin'] = null;

session_destroy();

header("Location: /test/index.php");

?>
```

Initially I reset the `signin` variable that way even if the session isn't destroyed the variable should have at least changed so that the system believes the user is logged out.

And at the top of my login page I have a condition to forward them to the home page if they are already logged in, that way that can't visit the log in page once already logged in. This portion looks like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['signin'] == 5)
{
        header("Location: /test/home.php");
}
?>
```

So in short, when someone is logged in, and clicks the link to logout it utilizes the first code block to log out, and then is forwarded to the page containing the second blcok of code.

However, this page still forwards me back to the home page, believing the user is still signed in and thus I'm guessing the signin variable was not reset.

Thoughts on how to solve my issue?

Comment: I think, that problem is that you haven't write exit, after header(); Check the value of session using something like `var_dump`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

session_destroy() does not unset any of the global variables within the session. Simply using:

```
session_unset();
```

to unset all global variables, or to only unset the specified variable, use:

```
unset($_SESSION['signin']);
```

Comment: NOTE: From the PHP manual: "Only use `session_unset()` for older deprecated code that does not use `$_SESSION`"!!!

Comment: Absolutely, good find. With regards to your answer, the PHP manual also suggests using unset($_SESSION) should always be avoided and you're also using (for some reason) the aforementioned deprecated $HTTP_SESSION_VARS in your own code.

Comment: +1 Hehe. Touche and that will shortly be removed from the codebase and commited (win-win) ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
session_unset()
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to use

```
$_SESSION['signin'] = null;
```

using `session_destroy();` should be enough

and I don't exactly know the deep stuff of PHP, but if you set a $_SESSION variable to NULL, PHP could read it as it is set to NULL which means 'it is set'? (don't know for sure though)

Comment: Yes, $var = null, is setted variable with value null; but isset($var), will return false; but in same time is_null($var) will return true :) such a funny language :P

Answer (score 0):

In this case, if you want to destroy a variable, you could do this:
Have a page named logout.php and whenever the user needs to logout, redirect him/her to that page. Now, inside that page you'll put the following, and here I'll explain you what this does:

```
<?php
session_start(); //Initializes the session
unset($_SESSION['thenameofyoursession']); //This unsets a specific session, so the user is logged out, in this case it would unset "thenameofyoursession".
$URL="/test/home.php"; //This is the redirect URL
header ("Location: $URL"); //This basically will send the user back to the redirect URL using header.
die(); //terminates the PHP script from running
?>
```

With that you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure is fairly obvious and similar to one that we use, however, it would be best to `unset()` the entire session if nothing in it is valid. -- If they aren't logged in, no session variables should exist.

**My `logout.php` script includes this:**

```
session_start();

session_register("loginMessage");
session_unregister("authenticatedUser");
session_destroy();

// relocate back to login page
header("Location: /");
```

Which works. `session_unset()` is historically redundant.

Hope this helps.